# Powershell parameter $args[0] with quotes

Tags: powershell

I'm running a PowerShell script invoked from a  batch that  pass a filename as first parameter.
Inside the script I use:

```
$file = Get-Item -LiteralPath $args[0]
```

But when the filenames contains a quote (I.E: `my'file.txt`) the `get-item` triggers an error. I've tried to remove the `-LiteralPath` parameter but the problem is the same.
The syntax of the script is

$file = Get-Item -LiteralPath $args[0]
write-host $file
cmd /c pause

If I run the script against my'file.txt I get:

- C:\m\tag\testscript.ps1 'C:\m\tag\my'file.txt' <<<<

  - CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

Comment: Be useful to know what the error is. If that quote is stripped out before the `Get-Item` is called then you would be getting `FileNotFound` type exception and that is not a fault of PowerShell but maybe the batch that is consuming the character.

Comment: Thnaks Matt: I get an error that says that the TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString.     I'm iserting more details on my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you are passing the path in this way in your file batch:

```
powershell.exe  C:\path\myscript.ps1 "%1%"
```

you need to escape the quote:

```
powershell.exe  C:\path\myscript.ps1 \"%1%\"
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you passing the parameter?

This works:

```
.{gi -literalpath $args[0]} "my'file.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that maybe by the time PowerShell sees the filename cmd has stripped off any surround double quotes so PowerShell sees the lone single quote as a parse error.  Try specifying the filename like so

```
my''file.txt
```